# Task is cancelled when it is running,My program can't go on running

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

List<Task> allTask = new List<Task>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    allTask.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        if (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }
        cts.Cancel();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("I'm doing it");
    }, cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current));
}

Task.WaitAll(allTask.ToArray());

Console.WriteLine("Implementation success!");

Console.ReadKey();
```

As for the problem, after the task was cancelled, my program does not go on running. Why is that? I clearly canceled it.
Why does my program have no output `"Implementation success"`?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking

Comment: Why does my program have no output Implementation success! This line of code。

Comment: The `return` statement is guilty. Change it to `break`

Comment: @Gonzalo Lorieto There's no way to be here Break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have similar problem, my task just work too long, and resolve like this:
In class xxx I have private collection :

```
private List<TaskWork> _taskCollection = new List<TaskWork>();
```

Add new task to list:

```
var cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
cancellationToken.CancelAfter(10000);

var taskWork = new TaskWorkVM
{
    CancellationToken = cancellationToken.Token,
    StartTime = DateTime.Now
};
taskWork.Task = Task.Run(() => { [some_work]; }, taskWork.CancellationToken);
_taskCollection.Add(taskWork);
```

Check is some task is completed, and remove from collection:

```
var completedTask = _taskCollection.Where(t => t.Task.IsCompleted).FirstOrDefault();

if (completedTask != null)
{
    _taskCollection.Remove(completedTask);
}
```

You can do while to check list, I think simple while is enough:

```
while (_taskCollection.Count() > 0)
{
    //do something
}
```

Task class have olso flag IsCanceled or you can use task status.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help,I'll practice it,If there's a better way, I'll tell you.

Comment: No problem, I glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

This is by design; calling `cts.Cancel()` will always throw a `TaskCanceledException` on the `WaitAll` call. So, your code queues 1000 tasks, gets to the wait all, an exception is thrown, and your program terminates.

Check out TPL docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children#example explicitly telling you how to handle this scenario by using an `AggregateException` handler checking for  `TaskCancelledException`s in the `InnerExceptions`.

If you want your code to get to the "Implementation Success" w/ proper handling of the cancellation, add an `AggregateException` handler:

```
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    List<Task> allTask = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        allTask.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return;
            }
            cts.Cancel();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("I'm doing it");
        }, cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current));
    }

    try
    {
        Task.WaitAll(allTask.ToArray());
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        //handle the cancelled tasks here, though you are doing it on purpose...
        Console.WriteLine("One or more tasks were cancelled.");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Implementation success!");

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I don't think it's necessary to collect the abnormality,Because it's a lot of time.Do you have a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. However, reading your other comment on @Clint's answer, I'm wondering if you want to terminate as soon as *any* of the tasks are cancelled? If so, you're looking for `Task.WaitAny`.  The behavior then would be that the exception would be caught on the first cancellation, and no waiting would happen on the rest. Otherwise, if you explain what you're looking for, that would help - I'm not sure that anyone will clearly understand what you're asking for from either of your comments.

Comment: I'm sorry.I don't know much English,I'm just using Machine Translation to talk to you,If used Task.WaitAny,Can't wait for all the tasks to end.